# how to create trigger in SQL server using two tables to find stock quantity

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, trigger

[image]

I have two table sales and purchase. I want to create a trigger which stores final quantity in stock table by subtracting sales table sold quantity from purchase table.

There is kikkat as a name n quantity are 10, 15 respectively and both quantities should be subtracted from purchase quantity table and it should be saved in the stock table.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a trigger I would suggest you to create a new column in the `purchase` table which will be a computed column.

Before creating it, create a scalar function which will accept `productname` or `productid` and returns `int`. Inside it, write a query to find the total from `sales` for that particular row (by passing `productname` or `id`) and subtract it from `purchase`'s quantity for that product.

If `purchase` can contain multiple entries for a particular product then create a separate table `Stock` and have columns as `ID, ProductName\Id, stockQuantity` (which will be a computed column as explained above).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a trigger is the right place for your application business logic. A stored procedure to update the corresponding rows in the stock table would be much more sensible in my opinion.

If you want to prevent users from modifying the sales and purchase tables directly without updating the stock table, don't grant permissions on those objects and let the stored procedure (your abstraction layer between the database and the application) do the needful.

In case you're wondering why I think that triggers are evil, take a look at this (old-ish) [post by Conor Cunningham](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/the-trouble-with-triggers/) or this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460316/are-database-triggers-evil).

BTW, if you want us to help you build the actual code of the stored procedure, you will have to provide much more than two screenshots of your table data. Please see [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for guidance on what to provide in order to ask a good T-SQL question.